# Multithreading: synchronize by locking

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Concurrent collection:

```
ConcurrentMap<LocalDate, A> ex = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

class A {
   AtomicLong C;
   AtomicLong D
}
```

How can I synchronize by locking "C" and "D"? That is, I need to change "C" and "B" at the same time with a guarantee that while I change the other one, the first one does not change from external actions.
Thank you.

Comment: Just control the access? Make the variables private and make sure you only have a single synchronized method that updates the variables at the same time.

Comment: The method that accesses these variables can work in different threads. It will be 100%, you just need to change these variables for the time being, put another appeal on the block. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, of course. Just `synchronize` on the same object, or lock the same `Lock`.

Comment: @Mary Synchronized does exactly that. The same synchronized method/object can only be called by a single thread at a time, any other threads have to wait, and can only proceed when the current thread using the synchronized has returned.

Comment: Consider making it immutable and replacing the object with `ConcurrentMap.compute()` or the like.

Answer (score 0):

#### What you're solving for

You are describing that you want to:

- allow a caller to modify something on an object
- prevent any other callers (other threads) from modifying things at the same time

---

#### Solution description

This solution uses `synchronized`, though there are number of other mechanisms available in Java that would support this (several of which are covered in
the [Lock Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html) section of the Java Tutorials).

The way "synchronized" works is that you designate some code using the "synchronized" keyword, along with an object to synchronize on.
When your code runs, the JVM will guarantee that, for all code which is synchronized – *on the same object* – only one thread
can proceed at a time.

---

You can make a synchronized code block, like below. Note: this defines an `Object` named "lock", but it's just a name chosen for clarity when
reading the code – you could name it anything you like.

```
Object lock;
synchronized (lock) {
    ... // all things here run only when "lock" is available
}
```

---

You can also designate an entire *method* as being synchronized, like this:

```
public void synchronized print() {
    System.out.println("hello");
}
```

This second example behaves like the first - it also locks on an object – but it's not clear at a glance what the object is; that is, how does
the JVM know which object to sychronize on? This approach works if the method itself is called on an object instance, and in that case the lock becomes `this`. I'll show an example below.

There's good info in the Java Tutorials about [synchronized methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html).

---

#### Solution #1: synchronized block using `Object lock`

Here are a few notes about a class `AllowOneEditAtATime`:

- it has two private members: `one` and `two`
- because they're private, they cannot be changed directly – so it would *not* be allowed to do something like this:

  ```
  AllowOneEditAtATime a = new AllowOneEditAtATime();
  a.one = new AtomicLong(1); // cannot change "one" directly because it is private
  ```
- defines `private Object lock` – this is meant to act as the thing that *two* different synchronized code blocks will lock on. It's totally fine to have different blocks of code each synchronize on the same object. This is the main technique you're after.
- uses a synchronized block inside `setOne()`, synchronizing on "lock"
- uses another synchronized block inside the other method – `setTwo()` – also synchronizing on "lock"
- because both `setOne()` and `setTwo()` are synchronized on the same object, one of them will be allowed to run at a time

```
class AllowOneEditAtATime1 {

    private Object lock;
    private AtomicLong one;
    private AtomicLong two;

    public void setOne(AtomicLong newOne) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            one = newOne;
        }
    }

    public void setTwo(AtomicLong newTwo) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            two = newTwo;
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Solution #2: synchronized block, using `this`

Solution #1 works fine, but it isn't necessary (in this case) to create an entire object just for locking. Instead, you can rely on the fact that
this code runs only after someone called `new AllowOneEditAtATime()`, which means there's always an object instance, which means inside the code
you can use `this`. The `this` keyword refers to the object instance itself, the actual instance of `AllowOneEditAtATime`.

So here's a variation using `this` (no more `Object lock`):

```
class AllowOneEditAtATime2 {

    private AtomicLong one;
    private AtomicLong two;

    public void setOne(AtomicLong newOne) {
        synchronized (this) {
            one = newOne;
        }
    }

    public void setTwo(AtomicLong newTwo) {
        synchronized (this) {
            two = newTwo;
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Solution #3: synchronized methods, implicit lock

Solution #2 works fine, but since we're using `this` as the lock, and since the code paths fit with doing this, we can use
[synchronized methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)
instead of synchronized code blocks.

That means we can replace this:

```
public void setTwo(AtomicLong newTwo) {
    synchronized (this) {
        two = newTwo;
    }
}
```

with this:

```
public synchronized void setOne(AtomicLong newOne) {
    one = newOne;
}
```

Under the covers, the entire `setOne()` method is synchronized on `this` automatically, so it isn't necessary to
include `synchronized (this) { .. }`
at all. In Solution #2, *both* methods were doing that, so both can be replaced.
By synchronizing both methods, they will both be synchronized on the object instance (`this`), which is similar to Solution #2, but with less code.

```
class AllowOneEditAtATime3 {

    private AtomicLong one;
    private AtomicLong two;

    public synchronized void setOne(AtomicLong newOne) {
        one = newOne;
    }

    public synchronized void setTwo(AtomicLong newTwo) {
        two = newTwo;
    }
}
```

---

Any of the above would work, as would other synchronization mechanisms. As with all things, there are multiple ways you could solve the problem.

For additional reading,
the [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) lesson (in Java Tutorials) has good info
and might be worth your time.